# Unable to play large mp4 video in JW player

Tags: html, jwplayer

I am using JW player in one of my recent website. It has capability to play mp4 video and it is playing well all mp4 video which is around 16 - 17 mb, but when the size increase more than 30 mb it stop playing it and showing error message "Error loading media: File could not be played" in firefox. In chrome it is showing only black screen on video player. I have attached screen shot. If you have any clue please tell. I have searched their forum but haven't find any solution.

Thanks in advance[image][image]

Comment: It's probably a problem with the encoding of the video or a server problem, so a screenshot doesn't tell us anything. There's certainly nothing in the JW Player script itself that is size-dependent. Please give us a link to your site.

Comment: It could be a maximum file size issue. Are you using an Apache webserver? if so add LimitRequestBody <filesize-in-bytes> to your httpd.conf file for your Apache config

Answer (score 0):

The url is https://berrytalented.com/talent/popup_video/42

For loggin to the site please use the following info:
username : emailme@ranasha.com
password : 123456

Can anyone please give us the solution